# Remote Python IDE for headless Pi0 device

Tags: remote

My 7yr old is having a fun time with the Camjam robot kit. We're using a Pi0 for the robot and SSH to log in and tinker with the code.

However, Nano is not a very nice IDE so I've installed sshfs to let him use Thonny on the client side -- but we still have to use SSH to run the scripts. Is there any way to tie in a Python IDE directly to the remote Pi so as to provide a simpler learning experience?

Comment: Nomenclature note: `nano` isn't an IDE at all, lol, it's just a *text editor* (and a very minimal one at that).  I'm not a python user and a quick search implies Thonny does not have remote integration, but I am sure there are ones that do.

Comment: research `remote desktop`

Comment: Please check out Thonny's homepage at the end of August, as I plan to release the first beta of Thonny 3.3 which supports remote back-ends via SSH.